# Rails gedcom gem, i get "stack level too deep" exception if i load a gedcom file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gedcom

i'm workling on a family tree analizer with Ruby on Rails. To parse a gedcom file i installed this gem: https://github.com/rbur004/gedcom

The documentation is kinda sporadic..
In the rails console, i entered

```
g = Gedcom.file("family.ged", "r:ASCII-8BIT")
```

which should load the file in g (the file is in the project root directory, so pathing should be fine). But i get the following error:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gedcom-0.9.4/lib/gedcom/gedcom_base.rb:125
```

The file itself should be ok, i can upload it to myheritage.com without any problems.

Comment: Which version of the gem are you using?